# Reading Negative decimal values in SSIS

Tags: ssis-2012

I m trying to read negative decimal values  for example -74.580 from flat file to sql table using SSIS package but I am facing errors.The column has data type as DT_CY i.e.currency in destination table.
While performing same task for non negative decimal values I read vales as string in source and without using any derived column or data conversion,they were loaded fine in with DT_CY datatype column in destination. But I m facing issues with negative values.Can you please help me with the datatypes,what I must use in Source and in transformations.
P.S. I have already tried converting column data type in source and transformation as DT_Numberic or DT_Decimal.I cannot change datatype in destination.All of my hit n trials did not worked(

Thanks in advance
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am no expert of the system. I am not sure of the solution here, just giving an advise. 
Sometimes negative currencies are stored as values in brackets. Please try converting negative values to positive values in bracket before loading.

Ex convert -74.580 to (74.580) and then try to load.